# git.exc.GitCommandNotFound: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Tags: python, git, ssh

Im learning Python.

Getting below exception while trying to clone a repos

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Selvakumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\git\cmd.py", line 622, in execute
        **subprocess_kwargs
      File "C:\Users\Selvakumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "C:\Users\Selvakumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
        startupinfo)
    PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "config_console.py", line 2185, in <module>
        command_line = ConfigCommandLine()
      File "config_console.py", line 87, in __init__
        g.clone('git@github.com:Modria/Ecomm_GM.git')
      File "C:\Users\Selvakumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\git\cmd.py", line 463, in <lambda>
        return lambda *args, **kwargs: self._call_process(name, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Selvakumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\git\cmd.py", line 905, in _call_process
        return self.execute(make_call(), **_kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Selvakumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\git\cmd.py", line 625, in execute
        raise GitCommandNotFound(str(err))
    git.exc.GitCommandNotFound: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

GitPython is installed. ssh keys are available in C:\Users\Selvakumar.ssh and its working when I clone from git bash. But the same not working from python. Please note that ssh keys are generated with no password. Please help me to resolve it

Comment: Can you make sure your python program runs in an environment where `HOME` is set to `USERPROFILE`? set `HOME=%USERPROFILE%`; call your python program (from a regulat CMD session, not a git bash).

Comment: Getting same error. I set HOME in environment variable and runs from CMD (which I was doing already)

Comment: Does your PATH references git binary?

Comment: Yes, that was the mistake I did. I missed to git.exe in GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE path  variable. Givenlike this asC:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe and works

Comment: Great! I have added an answer to document that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP confirms it is a PATH/variable issue

> > Does your PATH references git binary?
>
> Yes, that was the mistake I did. I missed to `git.exe` in `GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE` path variable.
>   Given like this as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe` and it works.

You can see that variable introduced [here in GitPython 26](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/26#issuecomment-1507078)

> If set, it should contain the full path to the git executable, e.g. `c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe` on windows or `/usr/bin/git` on linux.

The [GitPyhton README](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/3c6e5adab98a2ea4253fefc4f83598947f4993ee/README.md#requirements) states:

> GitPython needs the git executable to be installed on the system and available in your `PATH` for most operations.
>   If it is not in your `PATH`, you can help GitPython find it by setting the `GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE=<path/to/git>` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

seems like an authority error, be sure to run your script as an administrator

Comment: I tried that too. It doesn't work. BTW where does it look for SSH keys if I run as administrator